# CSS Custom Underlines

Tags: css, text

I'm trying to add a custom, extra-tall underline to my text.

It needs to fit in this syntax so I can place back into my WYSIWIG editor:

```
<p data-font-size="50px"><span style="letter-spacing:2px;">
  <span class="custom_one"><span style="color:#ffffff;">A software platform that makes 
  devices feel more human.</span></span></span>
</p>
```

Here's a picture of what I'm trying to do:

[image: picture]

Comment: Well, that's less of an underline, and more of a behind the text line. Since you want to retain inline text flow properties, I think everything along the lines of pseudo elements and absolute positioning is out of the question. Your best bet is a background gradient; but that is not something you want to cram into an inline style attribute, with all the vendor prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an underline, it's a background. You can use gradient:

```css
.custom_one {
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 60%, #333 60%);
  font-size: 42px;
}
```

```html
<p data-font-size="50px" style="background-color: #000;"><span style="letter-spacing:2px;">
  <span class="custom_one"><span style="color:#ffffff;">A software platform that makes 
  devices feel more human.</span></span>
  </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

@villain Or maybe this can help you?

```html
<p data-font-size="50px">
  <span style="letter-spacing:2px; background-color: gray">
    <span class="custom_one">
      <a style="color: white; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 10px solid black;" >A software platform that makes 
  devices feel more human.
      </a>
    </span>
  </span>
</p>
```